# How to access website from apache2 (linux from GCP) from other port than 80?

Tags: linux, apache, hosting, google-cloud-platform

I want to host a WordPress website on Google Cloud with Linux Instance.
There is already running website on port 80 and I want my new site to be hosted on any port other than 80.
I have changed following ports.conf and mywebsite.conf to achieve this

---

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf
```

Existing Code

```
Listen 80
```

New Code

```
Listen 80
Listen 8080
```

---

I have created following file with VirtualHost

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/mywebsite.conf
```

with Code

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
  ServerAdmin adminemail@gmail.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/mywebsite.com
  <Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
  </Directory>
  <Directory /var/www/mywebsite.com/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
  </Directory>
  ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
  <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
  # alert, emerg.
  LogLevel warn
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

After making these changes i just ran some commands as follows

```
$sudo a2ensite mywebsite.conf
$service apache2 restart
```

But when I hit my websites url as http://IPAdressOfServer:8080/ server is returning ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

What exactly I will have to do to make this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open the firewall port 8080 from your Google Project console. See this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list?project=[your-project-id]. Replace your-project-id with the id of your Google Project